# CSS: Header covering navigation menu, breaking hover effects

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on this website and have just noticed a problem with the div#top its covering the menu so you can only hover a link when just under the text. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
http://gridironstuds.com/

Comment: I don't see `a:hover` definition in google's dev tools

Comment: Just a note about the page you link: I personally have a strong dislike of pages that embed YouTube videos and start playing them automatically. Maybe let us press play ourselves? :)

Comment: @ultimatebuster That's not the problem. div#top is covering up part of the navbar. I'd recommend trying use the CSS property float on the logo image so that div#top isn't so big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used chrome inspector and simply changed this

```
div#top {position:absolute;}
```

to

```
div#top {position:static;}
```

and it fixed right up. Question though, why is your title in the body? It should be in the head of your html.

Comment: wow never knew this would work i thought static would make it stay at the top when you scroll. Thanks working so far for me haven't tested it in all browsers yet

Answer (score 1):

specify the height to the div#top{height:100px;} and reduce the size of logo image.

Answer (score 0):

You've nailed the problem: the `div#top` is covering the menus. To fix this, shorten the element: change its `height` attribute to something smaller (looks like 88px is about perfect).

Try your page with `<div id="top" class="centerContainer" style="height:88px;">`.

If that looks good, add that to your `div#top` rule in your `master.css`.

Comment: only problem is it cuts of the logo image and i need it to overlap the menu.

Comment: @josh Then you'll have to either float the image and use the margin to position it, or play with some divs and z-indexes.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using a z-index to bring the menu above the header image.  Then maybe the menu's background could be transparent so that it is still visible afterwards.

Comment: But the problem is when you hover on the menu it doesn't show the link.The Header Div is overlapping.If you put z-index,the problem remains same.

Comment: I notice that now.  I was figuring the z-index would be able to bring the menu div above the image, but it doesn't seem to work that way with the anchor.
Specifying the height to be 100px works.